# How to find current size (in memory) of table?

Tags: mysql

I have an in-memory table specified using engine=MEMORY. What command can I run to find out how much space it is currently taking? What about the maximum size?

Comment: Apparently the answer applies to all engines.

Comment: More details about the MEMORY engine: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename'\G
```

Where tablename is the name of the table you want to check.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT data_length+index_length table_size
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='whateverdatabase'
AND table_name='whatevertablename*'
AND engine IS NOT NULL;
```

This works for any table; does not works with views (engine IS NULL).