# Sqlite query to check size of column as byte

Tags: android, sqlite

I have tried search alot for how to get the memory size of table used in disk. I guess that it's not possible with SQLite.

I think. I could get the table size if I get the row size.
is there is query for Sqlite to check memory size of column as byte.

**for example**
I have table with these following fields.

Id (int)    Name (text) Img (blob).

How can I check total memory size of id, name, img used in a table.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite itself does not give you this information, but the [`sqlite-analyzer` tool](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) does.

If you want to do this from your app, you have to read all the record values and from those deduce how many bytes are used in the [on-disk record format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format).

Comment: how to use that analyzer tool?

Comment: @GajuKollur To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: sqlite3_analyzer provides lots of useful statistics, but does not break down space used by column as this question asks.

Answer (score -3):

you can get size of table from this .

[How to find current size (in memory) of table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286061/how-to-find-current-size-in-memory-of-table)

this may be for column

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/08d53163-5d40-49d0-a6ed-b1b1eccca235/

try this may be some of help you can find .

Comment: Thanks but this is not related to Sqlite this works on Mysql or Sql server