# Check how much space a single row takes in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there a way to check how much space a single row takes in Sqlite?

I have tried using this way:

I have 4 fields in my table:

```
id(int)
name(text)
pat(text)
is_default(bool)
```

```
 select *, sum(length(id)+length(name)+length(pat)+length(is_default)) 
    from color;
```

But it returns character length (for example: 43). How can I determine the row length in bytes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sqlite query to check size of column as byte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227358/sqlite-query-to-check-size-of-column-as-byte)

Answer (score 5):

SQLite itself does not give you this information, but the [`sqlite-analyzer` tool](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) does.

If you want to do this from your app, you have to read all the record values and from those deduce how many bytes are used in the [on-disk record format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format).

Comment: Hi CL. I'm trying to calculate the average size of a row. Would that be the "Average payload per entry" in the report?

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230267/check-how-much-space-a-single-row-takes-in-sqlite#13231215), determining the exact space occupied by a single row is not possible because -- among other reasons -- a row may not be a multiple of the page size, which is the main space unit of a database file.

The best one can do is compute an *approximate size* of each row, and then sum them up. [sqlite3_analyzer](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) is a viable option, but what if you need the row size within a `DML` statement? The following is focusing on the latter.

SQLite data storage is complicated because of its [dynamic typing system](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), unless `STRICT` is used on the table. Then there is the `TEXT` encoding that needs to be taken into account, which is solved in [v3.43.2](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_43_2.html) with `octet_length(TEXT)` that gives its exact binary size. `length(BLOB)` already does that for `BLOB`s. Then there is the variable size of `INTEGER` and even `REAL` in some cases. Then the question of whether there is a PK and an invisible `ROWID` column. And should indexes be taken into account as part of the table? And then you have all the [meta-data](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format).

All these aspects could be summarized into a `GENERATE ALWAYS ... VIRTUAL` column to give a quick and efficient row size estimate with a simple `SELECT size FROM table;` query.

I encourage people to propose insights on how to improve these estimates.