# how to check row size in encrypted table

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption

1) Situation: I use [sqlitecipcher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/) for Android, kindly provided by [commonsguy as a library module](https://github.com/commonsguy/sqlcipher-for-android-artifact) to store text in an encrypted database

2) Requirement: I need to inform the user about how much space an entry ("entry" should be read here as "database table row") takes on the disk

As far as I know, SQLite (and thus the sqlitecipher wrapper) does not provide an API to check the size of a row, and checking the byte count after reading an entry will give the size of non-encrypted text, so that information would be incorrect.

Of course I could AES the data again and check the size, but this would be a HUGE waste of processing power.

Are there any reliable formulas that allow to calculate how the amount of chars changes after the text is AES-encrypted? Or any other suggestions how to check the row size of an encrypted table?

Comment: I suspect that this will be difficult to do reliably. I'd cheat and come up with some heuristics based on tests, where you add entries with different values and see what the resulting file size delta is manually. Some things won't change much from entry to entry (e.g., size of an int). Some things will change a lot (e.g., size of a `BLOB`), but you should be able to come up with a formula that approximates the entry size given the sizes of its component parts. For extra credit, use regression analysis to come up with the formula. :-)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230267/check-how-much-space-a-single-row-takes-in-sqlite

Comment: thanks, test-based estimation is a possible solution, will have to check it. I only store text in the encrypted database. But wouldn't the size vary depending on the password (which is the encrypt/decrypt key in `sqlitecipher`)?

Comment: "But wouldn't the size vary depending on the password" -- not really. The user's passphrase is run through thousands of passes of PBKDF2, normalizing it into a long hash. That hash, though, is a consistent size. I am not aware that different hash values used as the actual encryption key will make a material difference in the resulting length of the encrypted data. That being said, you could try a few passphrases in your tests and see if that is indeed an independent variable to take into account. (and it's been a *long* time since I got to use "independent variable" in a sentence...)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/design/) **SQLite** encrypts on a **page level**. For this encryption, each page have then been extended with an initialization vector of **16 bytes** and a Message Authetication Code (HMAC_SHA1) of **20 bytes**.

With a default page size of **1024 bytes** and the extra **36 bytes**, this gives an overhead of 3.5%, that can be evenly distributed among the rows. Maybe a bit less depending on how much additional data are in the page.